# Can you make it easier to resize windows on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

Anyone know how to make it easier to grab the side or corner of the window to resize it? Seems like there is literally 1 pixel of space to grab.

Comment: Btw, I know this is a well-known bug. Just wondering if anyone has a workaround for now. Editing the theme perhaps?

Comment: This question seems like it might be better on SU or Ubuntu.SE

Comment: 2016 and this sh!t is still not fixed. They keep providing workarounds but not a solution. Is that _that_ difficult to fix??? What if I do not have a middle mouse button? what if I'm using touchpad and do not have the fingers of a piano player? what if I'm holding my child/coffee mug/use your imagination with the other hand? What if I've finally got the abilities of a piano player and have put my <use your imagination> away, and I want to resize the freakin' firebug? Guess what, None of the workaround works for that! Try it!

Comment: @Ejaz, here I am in 2022 looking for answers too. This bug is painful!

Comment: @GuilhermeTaffarelBergamin wow, I was pretty worked up by the bug then.... haha.

Comment: BTW I use tiling window manager now (i3) and mostly use keyboard shortcuts for resizing the floating windows or by using mouse as Dave's answer details.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Linux, you can usually hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag the right mouse button near one of the borders to resize a window, and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and the drag the left mouse button anywhere in the window to move it. I can't say for certain that this works on Ubuntu though!

**Edit:** This is based on my experience with fluxbox/openbox. There should be similar shortcuts for other window managers. According to [this link](http://www.kde.org/announcements/4.0/desktop.php), this should work with KDE. [This link](http://www.keyxl.com/aaae677/56/Linux-Gnome-Window-Manager-keyboard-shortcuts.htm) suggests it would be <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd> for GNOME.

Comment: Dunno about gnome, but this is not true of KDE. It might be good to state what assumptions you're making (with regard to DE/WM)

Comment: When i used KDE it was Alt-Right click, on gnome now it is Alt-Middle Click. At least for me.

Comment: Doesn't seem to... you can move the window like you say but no resizing. Hmm... just found a post that talks about it being a problem since ubuntu 6 so maybe there is no hope :S hehe.

Comment: AHH!!! YES! ALT+Middle click works a treat! I knew there would be some kind of command! Thanks a lot! LatinSuD :D

Comment: You could also switch to a saner theme; the new theme trends are not exactly friendly, even if they look smart.

Comment: The answer by @Snowcrash is what is needed for Ubuntu 18. This one no longer applies.

Answer (score 9):

Hold Alt and press Middle click (mousewheel) near the edge of the window and drag to resize it.

Answer (score 5):

Notes:

1. Super button usually has a Windows key on it
2. this is for GNOME

**Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10**

Move window: Super + hold down left mouse button

Resize window: Super + hold down middle mouse button

**Ubuntu 18.04**

Same as Ubuntu 20.04.

**Ubuntu 16.04**

Move window: Alt + hold down left mouse button

Resize window: Alt + hold down middle mouse button

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04 as well ! Thanks !

Comment: Why does this have to be so painful? It blows my mind that they have programmed a work around to it and not actually fixed the bug!

Answer (score 1):

Resize a window by dragging the edges or corner of the window. Hold down Shift while resizing to snap the window to the edges of the screen and other windows. Move or resize a window using only the keyboard. Press **Alt + F7** to move a window or **Alt + F8** to resize.