# In Linux Mate-window manager, Maximize length of window (keep width the same)

Tags: linux, window-manager

In windows, I double-click title bar of window  to maximize the window's length and keep the same width, how do I do that in Linux?  I'm running MATE in a AWS Linux2 Desktop.

I've done searches and found:

- [Can you make it easier to resize windows on Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/189119/can-you-make-it-easier-to-resize-windows-on-ubuntu) Nope
- Double-click on title in Linux makes window full screen (not what I want)
- Alt+F10 will maximize the window (not what I want).
- Alt+Right click and drag and resize the screen (nope).  Sometimes it's Super (or Windows-Key)+Right click and drag.
- Alt+F8 - resize without mouse.  (nope)

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: You are talking about Windows Snap to function. Not much to pick from. Try this:  https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1723/wintile-windows-10-window-tiling-for-gnome/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with Mate 1.22:

1. Open the Mate Control Center (alternatively, execute `mate-window-properties` in a terminal window and skip next step)
2. In the "Look and Feel" section, click on "Windows"
3. Go to the "Behaviour" Tab
4. In the "Titlebar Action" section, you should see a line titled "Double-click titlebar to perform this action"
5. Select "Maximize Vertically"

I have been using this option for a very long time so, if you don't have the same Mate version and the exact configurator interface, keep searching, you should find it somewhere.

Comment: It worked exactly as you described.  Perfect!   Thank you.  `cat /etc/os-release` says Amazon Linux 2.  This is the AWS workspace for Linux in case others are wondering.